# How do i close/restart my app when exit?

Tags: ios, ipad

i'm programming an IOS App for iPad in IOS5 and I want that when someone exit the app by pushing the home button it restart. I mean, if the person exit the app and then enter again i want it to start from the beginning not from when he left it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your "YourAppName-Info.plist" file, add the key-value pair "Application does not run in background" and set it to YES.